# push notification is not working in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send a push notification to mobile after solving user query,but it is not working. This is my code any issue, it is saying following error like this:

> Notice:Undefined variable,resultRequest in path/solvequery.php line no:15
>
> warning:cann't modify header information-headers already sent by(output  started at solvequery.php line no:15)in path/solvequery.php line 47...
>
> Notice:Undefined variable,resultRequest in path/solvequery.php line no:15
>
> warning:cann't modify header information-headers already sent by(output  started at solvequery.php line no:15)in path/solvequery.php line 47
>
> Notice:Undefined variable,resultRequest in path/solvequery.php line no:15
>
> warning:cann't modify header information-headers already sent by(output  started at solvequery.php line no:15)in path/solvequery.php line 47

solvequery.php:

```
       <?php
        include_once 'config.php';
        $id='';
        if(isset($_REQUEST['id_query']))
            $id = $_REQUEST['id_query'];
        if(isset($_REQUEST['requesttype'])&&$_REQUEST['requesttype']=='solve'){
            if(isset($_REQUEST['solve'])&&$_REQUEST['solve']=='solve')
            {
                $updateInfo['status']='Resolved';
                $date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $updateInfo['date_updated']=$date;
                $updateCondition=" id_query='".$id."'";
                $trueFalse=$db->update('query',$updateInfo,$updateCondition);


         $id=$resultRequest[0]['users_id_user'];
            $where="t.users_id_user='$id' AND";
            $query="SELECT t.device_id,t.platforms_id_platform as id_platform FROM tokens as t WHERE $where t.device_id!=''";
            $resultTokens=$db->select($query);
                if($resultTokens)
            {
                include_once 'Gcm.php';
                include_once 'Apns.php';
                $deviceTokens=array();
                $deviceTokens1=array();
                $alert='Your Query Solved';
                foreach($resultTokens as $token)
                {
                    if($token['id_platform']=='1'&&$token['device_id']!='')
                        $deviceTokens[]=$token['device_id'];
                    if($token['id_platform']=='2'&&$token['device_id']!='')
                        $deviceTokens1[]=$token['device_id'];
                }
                if(count($deviceTokens)>0)
                {
                    $apns=new Apns();
                    $apns->apnsPush($deviceTokens,$alert);
                }
                if(count($deviceTokens1)>0)
                {
                    $gcm = new GCM();
                    $message = array("m" => $alert);
                    $result = $gcm->send_notification($deviceTokens1,$message);
                }
            }



            }
            header("Location: query.php");
        }
        $query="SELECT u.name,u.email,u.phone,q.id_query,q.subject,q.status as reqstatus,q.description,q.date_created FROM users as u,query as q WHERE q.id_query='$id' AND q.users_id_user=u.id_user";
        $resultRequest=$db->select($query);

        foreach($resultRequest as $request)
        {
        ?>
        <div class="wrapper" style="width:380px;">
                <div class="fluid">
            <form name="frmRequest" action="solveQuery.php" method="POST">
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="grid3"><label>Name:</label></div>
                    <div class="grid9 check"><?php echo $request['name']?></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="grid3"><label>Subject:</label></div>
                    <div class="grid9 check"><?php echo $request['subject']?></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="grid3"><label>Query:</label></div>
                    <div class="grid9 check"><?php echo $request['description']?></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="grid3"><label>Status:</label></div>
                    <div class="grid9 check"><?php echo $request['reqstatus']?></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="grid3"><label>Queried on:</label></div>
                    <div class="grid9 check"><?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($request['date_created']))?></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <?php if($request['reqstatus']!='Resolved'){?>
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="grid3"><label>Solve:</label></div>
                    <div class="grid9 check"><input style="margin-top:5px;" type="checkbox" id="solve"  name="solve" value="solve" /></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>        
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id?>" name="id_query">
                <input type="hidden" value="solve" name="requesttype">
                <div class="formRow">
                    <div class="status" id="status1"></div>
                    <div class="formSubmit">

                        <input class="buttonM bGreen" id="next1" value="Submit" type="submit"/>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
                <?php }?>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
           }
        ?>
```

Comment: These are Notices and warnings, not errors. Just define the variable and the notice will go away, thus the warnign will go away, because no notice will be output before the headers get modified.

Comment: so, how i have to define that ......

Comment: like $resultRequest = NULL; before it is filled the first time. Or $resultRequest = ''; or $resultRequest = []; Whatever suitable for you.

Comment: ok....i have to decleare initially

Comment: btw. you are using $id=$resultRequest[0]['users_id_user']; on line 15, but $resultRequest gets filled for the first time on line 53 ($resultRequest=$db->select($query);) .. Your code is quite messy... :(

Comment: i'm getting one more error if i decleare $resultRequest=NULL

Comment: of course you do, you are trying to access  $resultRequest on line 15, if you set it to NULL beforehand, you get an error upon accessing it. You cannot access variables that are not set!

Comment: Please remove $id=$resultRequest[0]['users_id_user']; from line 15, $id is not used anywhere afterwards, I think you got it there by incident.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix this problem first:

```
Notice:Undefined variable,resultRequest in path/solvequery.php line no:15
```

You access the variable `$resultRequest` but did not define it beforehand. When this error does not show up anymore, your the second problem should also disappear.